# Using https module for http requests

Tags: node.js

I am now using the [`https` module](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) to send some https POST requests.

A new requirement came up: the server's SSL support may be switched on or off. So I must use either `https` or `http` accordingly.

**How do I send `http` requests using the `https` module? (the opposite would be helpful too)**

According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) for function `https.request(options[, callback])`,

> `options.protocol` Defaults to `https:`

---

I tried changing this to `http:`, for example,

```
 var options = {
        protocol: "http:",
        ...
    };
 https.request(options, function (res) { ... });
```

but got error
`Error: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just switch between modules.  You could even do something like this:

```
(url.substr(0, 5) === 'https' ? https : http).request(...)
```